# How can you tell the video delivery protocol used from within a browser?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

Videos in webpages can be delivered through different protocols like MPEG-DASH, HLS, WebRTC, etc. Is there a way from a browser to understand what protocol is being used?

Answer (score 2):

If we are talking purely streaming video delivery, i.e. typically protected content, or content that is preencoded. There are 3 major delivery mechanisms normally being used:

- Simple "HTTP" streaming. This happens when someone placed a MP4 or other playable video file and simply links to it in a  tag. If you look at the network tab of your browsers developer tools, it should be fairly obvious because you can see the request to the single file.
- Safari and Edge specifically also supports Apple's HTTP Live Streaming directly in the  tag, this might also be supported on some Android devices. In this case, you can look for requests to files ending in "m3u8" which is the HLS manifest. There is no guarantee that it is named that way, but most cases are.
- MPEG-DASH or Smooth Streaming or any other streaming variant implemented using [Media Source Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/). In this case, you might look for urls ending in .mpd or /Manifest to identify MPEG-DASH and Smooth Streaming respectively. But there are no guarantees, and for instance Netflix tends to have URLs where you need to look at the content to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC usage will show in chrome://webrtc-internals in Chrome or about:webrtc in Firefox